# I have 2 versions of Apache running on my system

Tags: macos, apache, osx-yosemite

There is another version of `apache` running on my system.
When in run `sudo apachectl stop` I still get the "**It Works**" page

So I found the location of the other version that is still running and it looks to be an older version which probably came pre-installed and is located in `/opt/local/apache2/`.

I tested this file `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html.sample` by just changing the text and then checked the browser again.

```
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
```

I want to remove that one and keep the latest version which is located in `private/etc/apache2`

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
```

How can I do this safely.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9252, also try `ps ax` for starters.

Comment: Ok i can see where the other apache config is :

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this

I ran ps `aux | grep apache` to see the apache processes

I then ran `sudo apachectl stop`

Then sudo `killall -9 httpd` to kill **all apache** processes

Then `sudo apachectl restart`

I went to the browser and typed `localhost~/username/sitename`

**Bingo** it works again, my system is using the correct version of apache again!

Comment: The one in `opt` is likley from Macports. You san stop it at any time with `sudo apache2ctl stop` or `sudo port unload apache2`. You can deactivate it with `sudo port deactivate apache2` and completely uninstall it with `sudo  port uninstall apache2`.